# Combinations of a jigsaw

Tags: combinatorics

I'm just asking myself of how many combinations you would have to go through to solve a jigsaw puzzle by "brute force" if you have $n = (p \times q)$ pieces. To simplify that, I assume that there are no jigsaw pieces with flat edges so that *every* piece can be at *every* position.

I've came up with this for the number of combinations $C$:
$$C(n) =  n! * 4^n$$
$n!$ would be the number of options to arrange the pieces and for each of these options there should be $4^n$ possibilities to rotate them.

Can anyone verify that? Or am I doing a mistake?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's right.

But it assumes that you can only detect that you have something wrong once you put down the last piece. Usually one can notice that *without* all pieces placed that the ones that are placed yet don't match up. Doing so leads to a *branch-and-bound* search which can be quite a bit faster if you're good at detecting wrong branches early.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Yes, I'm aware of that limitation but I just wanted to knew how mouch steps it's going to take in the _worst_ case.

Comment: One of all these combinations will solve your puzzle, only upside-down :)

Comment: How do you mean that?

Comment: One of your many combinations $C(n)$ is also a solution of the puzzle, but upside down, i.e., rotated 180 degrees. Would that also solve your puzzle? I was (jokingly) suggesting that the worst case scenario would be one step faster.